# Every command is returning 'bash: <command>: command not found...'

Tags: linux, shell

I just installed Scala and added the path with `gedit ./bashrc`:

```
export SCALA_HOME=/home/avijit/scala-2.12.2
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:PATH
```

but since then, no command is working:

```
[avijit@localhost-localdomain ~]$ ls
bash: ls: command not found...
```

I gave the full path but:

```
[avijit@localhost-localdomain ~]$ /home/avijit/.bashrc
bash: /home/avijit/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

Even vi is not working so that I can fix the mess in the path.

```
[avijit@localhost-localdomain ~]$ vi /home/avijit/.bashrc
bash: vim: command not found...
[avijit@localhost-localdomain ~]$ sudo /home/avijit/.bashrc
bash: sudo: command not found...
[avijit@localhost-localdomain ~]$ echo $path
```

<- returned blank line

I tried many steps from different forums but no luck. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have messed up your `PATH` variable. Try `echo $PATH` and make sure it includes `/bin:/usr/bin/:` at minimum. If it doesn't, then set it with `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:` and give it another try. (the `':'` separates path components -- add as many components as you need)

Comment: if echo $PATH returns blank line means, you didnt set up the path correctly. Set the path correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with `export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:PATH` in this you missed `$`.

Update default variable as `PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: But how do I bring up the editor at the first place? i.e. how to edit the path. Nothing is.working. Plz Plz suggest any working command to edit the bashrc file

Comment: You can start `/usr/bin/sh` or `/usr/bin/gedit` or as mentioned by David.CR in comment section set path to default `/bin:/usr/bin:` and then update